# How to add C files to the Android Source Code

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a file written in C that I want to add to the Android source code that I have downloaded on my PC.  I believe I have the file in the correct folder but what else do I need to do?  I believe I have to edit a Make file to include the name of the C file but which Make file would I edit?  There are hundreds of them.

Comment: should it be a standalone executable or some library or do you want to add it to an already existing module?

Comment: Hundreds of Make files? This sounds like a problem very specific to your project. Try asking someone who worked on the code to give you more insight...

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a look at the JNI and the NDK to include some C/C++ libraries into your Android application. It is not as straight forward as what you might think. Check this link for more info or the related question on Stack Overflow http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/overview.html

**Edit:**

Have you looked at this doc ? http://source.android.com/source/building.html (and the previous pages about the setup and such?) If it's just a file replacement in the native source  code, there should be no makefile to modify, just build the whole project through the commands given in the link provided by Google and it should be just fine.

Using

```
$ make -j4
```

For example after the init and the target selection for a compilation with 4 different threads. This will look for the main Makefile and the internal job is not of your business, so it should be alright.

Seems it seems you have to add a new file, you might wanna look at the other files on which your new file depends (see the include sections on your file), then using your favorite Linux command utility search among all the Makefile to find where those files your new c file requires are located, it might give you a head start.

Anyhow, if you didn't develop this new source file, why is it for you to build an image based on it, or why don't you have some further details about it ?

Comment: Thank you for the help.I was told by the person who wrote the file that I don't actually use the NDK for this. The .c file is compiled into the system's source code.  I just have to figure out where it goes and how to get it included when I do I build.

Comment: @user1682137: Could describe by updating your question what exactly you are trying to do, what is a the project (Android one or native one ?), if you want to modify the Android image, because right now it's really unclear what you are exactly trying to achieve. Maybe you just want to rebuild the Android system image using a specific .c file that will replace the original for a tweak, is that correct ?

Comment: @user1682137: See my original post edited for more info about the build process

Comment: Thanks Vincent for your help.  Here is a little background on the project.  I have a C file called "leds-mark.c"  It is a file that modifies the blinking LED lights on the phone.  I was told I need to put it in the android source code and compile it.  I have downloaded the android source code and I have been able to build it and flash the image on the phone successfully without the new file.  So I'm just trying to figure out where it goes and how to do this.  I'll paste the first part of the file.  I'm assuming it should go in the same place as all the files listed after the #include statement

Comment: /*
 * Fast blinking LEDs driver for GPIOs
 *
 * Copyright (C) Samsung telecommunications america inc.
 * Mark sungmin hong <sungmin.h@samsung.com>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 */
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
....

Comment: Thank you for the more detailed info. However the header you show me are the linux kernel files, if you new file doesn't replace an existing one or do not override some existing function, adding it will change nothing since the existing source code will not reference/include/call it. Are you sure you don't have to hook-up this new class with an existing file ? For example replace a "StockLeds.c" with your "leds-mark.c" or such ? Also why don't you have a .h file with it ? Still hard to know what to do without further info !

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what other files belong to the component you're going to change you can try to find a Makefile listing them (in some way). Probably in the same directory, probably Android.mk

Comment: Yeah, that is what I probably need to do.  However, there are hundreds of Android.mk files so I'm unsure which one I am using.